# Free cross-platform library to convert numbers (money amounts) to words?

Tags: c++, c, cross-platform, free

I'm looking for cross-platform library which I can use in my C application to convert money amounts (e.g. $123.50) to words (one hundred twenty three dollars and fifty cents). I need support for multiple currencies: dollars, euros, UK pounds etc.

Although I understand this is not hard at all to write my own implementation, but I'd like to avoid reinventing wheel. I've tried to google it, but there is too much noise related to MS Word converters.

Can anybody suggest something?

**UPDATE** numerous comments suggest to write my own implementation because it's really easy task. And I agree. My point was about support of multiple currencies in the same time and different business rules to spell the amounts (should be fractional part written as text or numbers? etc.) As I understand serious business applications have such library inside, but I think there is nothing open-source available, maybe because it seems as very easy task.

I'm going to write my own libary and then open-source it. Thanks to all.

Comment: I'd be surprised, simply because it would be so simple to write. In fact, it would make a rather good CS homework problem...

Comment: @T.E.D.: although not asked, i18n might be a bit more tricky, so there a library could come in handy.

Comment: I don't see how the currency type is relevant. A number is a number. I also don't see how cross-platform is relevant. This is a purely computational problem with no OS/platform interaction whatsoever, so it would take a sadist to write an implementation that's not completely portable.

Comment: @R..: The words "dollars" and "cents" are part of the word string.  Other currencies would have different words.  For example, pounds and shillings describe British currency.

Comment: Ah. I was thinking of standard US check form, "One hundred twenty-three and 50/100" with "dollars" as a separate word after the field.

Comment: @R.. the words "dollars/cents", "euro/cents" and "pounds/pence" is important to have.

Comment: @bialix:  I couldn't find anything with a Google search.  R.. brought up a good point.  There is check writing software, but the word string would be "One hundred twenty-three and 50/100".  I suspect you're going to have to write your own conversion functions.

Comment: If you only support values up to a fixed maximum, this is a very finite problem. Just enumerate all the cases and handle them. It only gets hard if you support bignum values up into the googles and googleplexes. "That will be 1 googleplex dollars and fifty cents, please." :-)

Comment: In the UK the string on a cheque would be One hundred twenty-three pounds 50 - so it is really not just a number

Comment: I highly suggest talking to some university students.  This is usually an assignment in introductory language classes.

Comment: I had this exact task in an interview not too long ago.  Yes, it's pretty simple to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? It's not a complete solution as it externalizes the handling of the currency. Furthermore, it fails for negative numbers.

Just allocate a character buffer and call `write_number`. The third and fourth argument are expected to be the currency units (in their plural form), e.g. "dollars" and "cents". (The singular case isn't properly handled yet.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

const char* SMALL_NUMBERS[] = {
    0, "one ", "two ", "three ", "four ",
    "five ", "six ", "seven ", "eight ", "nine ",
    "ten ", "eleven ", "twelve ", "thirteen ", "fourteen ",
    "fiftenn ", "sixteen ", "seventeen ", "eighteen ", "nineteen "
};

const char* TENS[] = {
    0, 0, "twenty ", "thirty ", "forty ",
    "fifty ", "sixty ", "seventy ", "eighty ", "ninety "
};


void append_lt_1000(char* buf, int num)
{
    if (num >= 100) {
        strcat(buf, SMALL_NUMBERS[num / 100]);
        strcat(buf, "hundred ");
        num %= 100;
    }
    if (num >= 20) {
        strcat(buf, TENS[num / 10]);
        num %= 10;
    }
    if (num != 0)
        strcat(buf, SMALL_NUMBERS[num]);
}

void append_mag(char* buf, double* number, double magnitude, const char* mag_name)
{
    if (*number < magnitude)
        return;

    append_lt_1000(buf, (int)(*number / magnitude));
    strcat(buf, mag_name);
    *number = fmod(*number, magnitude);
}

void write_number(char* buf, double number, const char* major_unit, const char* minor_unit)
{
    double ip, fp;

    buf[0] = 0;
    fp = modf(number, &ip);

    if (ip == 0) {
        strcat(buf, "zero ");
    } else {
        append_mag(buf, &ip, 1000000000000.0, "trillion ");
        append_mag(buf, &ip, 1000000000.0, "billion ");
        append_mag(buf, &ip, 1000000, "million ");
        append_mag(buf, &ip, 1000, "thousand ");
        append_lt_1000(buf, (int)ip);
    }
    strcat(buf, major_unit);

    if (fp != 0) {
        strcat(buf, " and ");
        append_lt_1000(buf, (int)(fp * 100));
        strcat(buf, minor_unit);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for example of the code. As I said in my original question there is nothing complex to write my own implementation, I was more concerned about currency and singular/plural handling. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) has exactly this, and an API to build your own rules for number->text, for spelling out. See [here](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/numbers).